# NuGet package from PCL

Tags: xamarin, nuget, visual-studio-2017, portable-class-library

I have a **PCL** library I want to distribute as NuGet package.

Screenshot of the PCL application library properties page:
[image: screenshot.001]

csproj file:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile111</TargetFrameworkProfile>
<ProjectTypeGuids>{786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

## Steps to reproduce my problem:

1. Clone both repos from:

   - [NuGet package](https://github.com/stannynuytkens/NugetPackage)
   - [Console application + PCL library](https://github.com/stannynuytkens/NugetConsole)
2. Build the [NugetPackage](https://github.com/stannynuytkens/NugetPackage) project + `nuget spec` + `nuget pack`
3. Create a local nuget package repository pointing to the project folder.
4. Open the [NugetConsole](https://github.com/stannynuytkens/NugetConsole) solution and try installing the package in both projects.

Some references I used:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/target-frameworks
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec
- https://portablelibraryprofiles.stephencleary.com/
- http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/05/framework-profiles-in-net.html

Comment: How about not using PCL but .NET Standard instead?

Comment: I would clear your caches, both machine cache and solution's packages directory, to make sure you do not have an old .nupkg that is out of date and does not have any assemblies in its lib directory.

Comment: Agree with Matt. According to your description, I have created a nuget package, https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ai1sp_yvodHfhE5bxnyGmwev3ue_. Installed it to console application and PCL project, both of them works fine. So please try to delete the packages folder in the solution folder, or install theat package in a new solution NOT project.

Comment: @MattWard that was indeed "a" problem. I'm updating my question with new findings, please advise. DotNet Standard is a no go for now because of unit tests...

Comment: I think my real question is; How can I make a nuget package from a PCL library and use it in a PCL library.. (took me some time to figure out the actual question)

Comment: @grmbl, Any update for this issue? Could you make a nuget package from a PCL library and use it in a PCL library now?

Comment: Yes @LeoLiu-MSFT, it works thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make a nuget package from a PCL library and use it in a PCL library?

I have downloaded your nuget package and test projects, I can created the nuget package and installed it to the both projects. Following are my detailed steps:

**1. Create nuget package:**

Download the nuget project, then build the project+`nuget spec`+`nuget pack`:

Here is the `.nuspec` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>My.Package</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Tester</authors>
    <owners>Tester</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2018</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
  </metadata>
    <files>
       <file src="bin\**" target="lib\portable-net45+wp8\" />
    </files>
</package>
```

**Note:** Since you are planning use this package into PCL library, so the target should be `.net45` + `Profile49`, according to the document [Portable Class Library (PCL) profiles](https://portablelibraryprofiles.stephencleary.com/), nuget target should be **portable-net45+wp8**:

[image]

[image]

**2. Install that package to both projects:**

Download those two test projects from GitHub, and open it with Visual Studio 2017, then copy the created package to the local nuget feed:

Open Package manager Console, install the package with following command:

```
install-package My.Package -source D:\LocalServer
```

[image]

So the nuget package is correct install in both projects.

**Note:** I have seen following code in your project file of console application:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="My.Package">
      <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Please remove it, this is not a correct way to add nuget package.

Comment: What's wrong with using PackageReference? Everywhere I look they talk about migrating from Packages.Config to using PackageReference in the csproj files?

Comment: This should be work for Packagereference. Not all projects need use the packagereference, this is used for the new type .csproj project. http://www.natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/ and https://blog.nuget.org/20170316/NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild.html