# How to make custom libraries in Xamarin and import to seperate applications?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile, shared-libraries

I need to create a Xamarin library that contains few activities and logic. Then I need to import it to the main application and use it. I'm using visual studio for development. Is this possible to do? I have done this in android studio with .aar files but not sure in c#

Comment: Yes.  Create a new project in VS using the Android Library template

Comment: Is it Andriod Class Library?

Comment: It is possible to do with a Android Class Library.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I created an android class library. It uses 1additional dependency as well. When the dll files of the class library are added to the main application, it fails to load that dependency. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**It is possible.**

You only need to create a Xamarin.Android Java Bindings Library from an Android **.AAR** file.

We'll use the following steps to create a Bindings Library from the **.AAR** file:

1. Create a new Java Bindings Library project.
2. Add a single .AAR file to the project. A binding project may only contain a single .AAR.
3. Set the appropriate build action for the .AAR file.
4. Choose a target framework that the .AAR supports.
5. Build the Bindings Library.

Once we've created the Bindings Library,  we can use the Bindings Library in xamarin android project.

More detail info can refer to **[Binding an .AAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar)**.

Comment: I don't have an .AAR file. What I want is implement a module in Xamiran as a module/library and reuse it by importing to the main application

Comment: @SidathAsiri Okey, if without using native library, you can create a Nuget Package for Xamarin Android to use. Have a look at this document(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-packages-for-xamarin).

Comment: @SidathAsiri If not want to install NugetPackage, also can create a [Portable Class Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/pcl?tabs=windows) for xamarin android.

Comment: I created an Andriod class library and imported it to the main application. I faced 2 problems.
 1. Dependencies of the library is not added to the main application automatically. I have to add them again.
 2. Permission request is not popped out from the main application
How to fix these issues?

Comment: @SidathAsiri The second question I have replied from your another question. The first question not too much understanding, you could detail about can not adding library automatically.

Comment: Thanks your solution helped me. Other question is, my Android class library uses a few NuGet dependencies. After the class library is built and add to the main application, it fails to load those NuGet dependencies. How to build the library including those dependencies as well?

Comment: @SidathAsiri About this problem, you could have a look at this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319497/nuget-package-from-pcl

Comment: What I have is an Android Class Library (Xamarin) template project. Is this a PCL?

Comment: Able to fix this by referring https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#from-a-visual-studio-project

Comment: @SidathAsiri Glad have solved that! You could update this in answer, then other people will know how to solve that.