# How to open an activity created from Android Studio from Xamarin?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xamarin, mobile

I have created a module from Android Studio including some activities. I have created a binding library and imported this to a Xamarin project. How can I invoke that activity that created in the module from Xamarin? When I observe the imported module from the object browser, I noticed that The main activity is missing. All the other classes were there. Is this not possible to do?

Comment: Hi, do mean want to use the methods from the module created from Android Studio? I have answered about binding .AAR in your [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64028258/how-to-make-custom-libraries-in-xamarin-and-import-to-seperate-applications/64038980#64038980), you can have  a look at that, then check whether the module is used correctly. In general, if native android can use the module, xamarin android also will can do that.

Comment: Yes. I have added the AAR to the Xamalin application as a binding lib. What I don't understand is how to start an activity defined in bind library from Xamalin. In the android studio I used the following code to invoke the activity.

Intent intent = new Intent(com.example.ActivityName);
startActivity(intent);

How to do the same in Xamalin?

Comment: Okey, you can use follow way `Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ActivityName));this.StartActivity(intent);`.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't see the Activity class in the binding library. How that can happen? Only that class is missing in the binding library. I have defined it like this in Java
public final class OcrCaptureActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
// impl
}
}

Comment: Then you can use this: `Intent intent = new Intent();intent.SetClassName("PackageName", "ActivityName");this.StartActivity(intent);` to have a try. You need to type the name of Package and Activity.

Comment: This worked. But from the library, I request the camera permission. The permission request option is not getting popped and it throws a permission error message. How to handle this?

Comment: The [Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=android#using-permissions) class provides the ability to check and request runtime permissions.You could have a try witht this.